# Error creating electron executable files for production

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

I'm new in Electron and the problem that I have is when I try to create an executable file.
I've tried many exemples and always I have the same problem. The executable file is created but when I try run it, don't work.

Appears the following error in a windows dialog

> [Window Title] Error
>
> [Main Instruction] A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
>
> [Content] Uncaught Exception: Error: Unable to find a valid app
>       at Object. (D:\Projects\angular\my-electron-app\packages\my-electron-app-1.0.0-win32-ia32\resources\electron.asar\browser\init.js:121:9)
>       at Object. (D:\Projects\angular\my-electron-app\packages\my-electron-app-1.0.0-win32-ia32\resources\electron.asar\browser\init.js:188:3)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:642:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:653:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:683:10)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:196:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:622:3
>
> [OK]

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-electron-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"ng serve\" \"npm run electron\"",
    "electron": "electron ./src/electron.dev",
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "package:win": "npm run build && cross-var electron-packager dist $npm_package_name-$npm_package_version --out=packages --platform=win32 --arch=all --overwrite "
     ...
}
```

How can I fixed this?

Comment: do you have package.json in  ./electron directory?

Comment: what directory are you talking about? where I need to have this directory?

Comment: do you point to a build browser app?

Comment: I've used this exemple https://medium.com/@PhilippKief/angular-desktop-apps-a9ce9e3574e8 but didn't work

Comment: Thanks guys, with yours comments I found the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After studied a lot I found the solution, I don't know if it's the best way, but works.
When I was executing the build for my application, in my file "angular.json" had the property outputPath with this way: "outputPath": "dist/my-electron-app", but to generate my windows packge I needed only "dist".
In this way when I execute de command:

```
"package:win": "npm run build && cross-var electron-packager dist $npm_package_name-$npm_package_version --out=packages --platform=win32 --arch=all --overwrite "
```

it will generate only the folder "app" over my "electron\resources\" with the correct files, before that it generated the folder "app/my-app"

Thanks